# Cholesky Decomposition And Multivariate Distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I'm studying multivariate distributions in general and I keep coming across an expression like:

$X = \mu + A Y$ where $ \mu $ and $A $ are constant vectors of dimensions  d x 1 and d x k respectively. Then $X$ is d x 1 and $Y$ k x 1.

Then theres an expression saying $ \Sigma = AA'$ and my lecturer mentions how we get $A$ via cholesky decomposition. Here's what I dont understand. if $A$ is d x k , i.e. not necessarily a square matrix, how can it be derived using cholesky if cholesky only produces square matrices, at least I think it does. It also seems strage to me that k can be larger or smaller then d, but I think it makes some sense. For example say k was 1, in which case $X$ would be generated from a single univarite distrbution $Y$. Or if d was 2 and k was 5 then $X$ would be a bivarite distribution generated from a linear combination of those distributions making up $Y$ of dimension 5... This second part, which is a bit fuzzy in my head, I think is okay but I really am struggling to understanding how $A$ can be non-square if it's derived using choleskly decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Sigma$ is positive definite, then it is full rank, and your Cholesky decomposition must be square. This is because
$$
d = rank(\Sigma) = rank(AA') = rank(A) \le \min(d,k).
$$

More info:

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782790/relation-between-rank-of-a-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrix-and-its-numbe

Answer (score 1):

Your doubts are right: A matrix $A$ that fulfills $\Sigma = AA'$ for a given symmetric positive semidefinite $\Sigma$ is not unique at all. For example, once you have found such an $A$, the matrix $B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\begin{array}{cc}A
 & A\end{array})$ would be another solution.

Using a Cholesky decomposition is just *one* way to find such an $A$, if $A$ is allowed to have the same size as $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma$ is positive definite. If $A$ is further required to be a triangular matrix, then the Cholesky decomposition is the only unique solution (and in fact, the Cholesky algorithm is the most efficient way to find it). But in general, $A$ is not unique.

This is of no *distributional* concern if you consider multivariate normal distributions. But have in mind if you want to simulate such random variables, that the single realizations again depend on the choice of $A$, of course. For more general models of $Y$, the choice of $A$ influences even the distribution of $X$.

Now what if $A$ is $k\times d$ and $k<d$? Then, $\Sigma$ is a singular matrix. Such distributions exist, but they don't have a density w.r.t. the Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, the multivariate normal distribution defined via this density doesn't permit singular $\Sigma$. So if $X$ follows a multivariate normal distribution, you can rely on the Cholesky decomposition.

If you still want to find $A$ in such a non-square setting, you can use a singular value decomposition. But again: This is no unique solution.